# Best approach for creating dynamic config-files

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to dynamically create config files for application, that should contain IP-address of the POD.

AFAIK it can be done using initcontainers, but what about deployments or rc?

Comment: Why do you need the IP of the pods? Couldn't you use the DNS address assigned for each deployment / service? (that is http://service.namespace)

Comment: I have a specific application that needs ip address in it's config

Answer (score 0):

Downward API is what you are looking for : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/

You can use this information to populate volumes or environment variables. You can define them on your deployment and they will get populated when pod is instantiated.

Comment: And how can I modify my config before starting application using those env variables?

Comment: the best way would be to incorporate env vars directly in your config, if the software you configure can deal with it. Worse, but viable is to put placeholders in your config files and have an entrypoint script that replaces them from envs before the final command is launched

Comment: If you want a on-disk-config-file written, then a combination of exposing the downward API and using an init-container to read the values there and write to a local volume location is probably your best solution.

Comment: I cannot use initcontainers with deployment, because " In 1.8, the annotations are no longer supported and must be converted to the PodSpec field." https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/